# Using delegate declaration in multiple classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

Let's say I have a class `ClassA` which declares a protocol in `ClassA.h`:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol

- (void)myMethod;

@end
```

Now, let's say I also have a class `ClassB`. I would really like to use the `SomeProtocol` in `ClassB` like so:

```
#import ClassA.h

@interface ClassB : NSObject
{
    id <SomeProtocol> someObject;
}
```

but the complier keeps telling me that it "Cannot find protocol declaration for "SomeProtocol".

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ClassB to look like this:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol;

@interface ClassB : NSObject
{
    id <SomeProtocol> someObject;
}
```

Just to clarify, using the @protocol directive like this just informs the compiler that SomeProtocol is a protocol that will be defined later.  This just make a forward reference to the protocol without needing to import the interface where it is defined.

More information can be found here (Very bottom): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the protocol in SomeProtocol.h (its own header file) and import it from both class A and class B.

If you don't import the protocol you'll not get nice compile time warnings telling you when you are making a mistake calling it...